# .NET Collection needed to store file paths and extensions

Tags: c#, collections, path

I have a huge amount of file paths and file extensions to deal with :

- Each file path has exactly one file extension associated with it.
- Each file extensions has one or more file paths associated with it.
- Paths are unique, extensions aren't.

**My goal is to easily retrieve all the file paths associated with a given file extension.**

For example, if I ask "mp3", I'd like to know all the paths of the files with that extension.

Now, my question is : Which C# collection should I use to optimally
 do this and how should I use that collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where the key would be the extension (for example, "mp3") which would return the list of file paths of type .mp3.

If you can use LINQ, you could use a single `List<string>` and retrieve file paths associated with a specific file extension like this:

```
List<string> s = new List<string>();
s.Add("c:\\documents and settings\\sound1.mp3");
s.Add("c:\\documents and settings\\sound2.mp3");
s.Add("c:\\documents and settings\\sound3.mp3");
s.Add("c:\\documents and settings\\something1.wav");
s.Add("c:\\documents and settings\\something2.exe");
s.Add("c:\\documents and settings\\abc.MP3");

var mp3paths = s.Where(x => String.Compare(".mp3", Path.GetExtension(x), true) == 0);
var exepaths = s.Where(x => String.Compare(".exe", Path.GetExtension(x), true) == 0);
```

Comment: Good quick draw, Marlon. Beat me by seconds.  Although I would suggest IEnumerable<string> rather than List.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! What is the advantage of IEnumerable over List?

Comment: It is generally better to use the least specific declaration and defer the implementation details.  IEnumerable allows you to pretty much use any specific collection in your implementation, a List, Array, etc.

Comment: @Reed -- You can declare the actual collection as a List, if you want, when you are building your Dictionary.  You add the items to the list, then add the List under the key. My assumption here is that the Dictionary is built and thereafter pretty much only referenced.  If you are regularly adding new items, then you can still defer type specifics by using ICollection<string>.

Comment: @BJ: You would need to pre-create the list, then add it, in order to do this.  In practice, it's much simpler if your using an ICollection implementation, because you can then build the list how Pwninstein did...

Comment: @Reed -- I probably would not nit pick on either in a code review. If there is a functional need for ICollection, either way can be expressed clearly in code.

Comment: Ungh, please use `.EndsWith()`!

Comment: `Path.GetExtension` clearly states the programmer's intention.

Comment: @Marlon: Since the string class is from mscorlib, the `.EndsWith` call is likely to be inlined.  "EndsWith" also clearly states the programmers intention, and is certainly much more performant.  In this case, the OP said that he had a HUGE amount of files and we aren't losing readability, so this is a perfect candidate for optimization.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply looking for a container to hold all of your extension and file path relationships, I'd suggest a `Dictionary` (specifically a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`).

That way you can store a list of strings (i.e. a list of file paths) per file extension.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
dictionary.Add("exe", new List<string>());
dictionary["exe"].Add("C:\Test\MyApp.exe");
dictionary["exe"].Add("C:\Test\AnotherApp.exe");
//Etc...
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the Dictionary already mentioned is a Lookup **if** the collection only needs to be set once and you want it to be immutable:

```
var myLookup = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\samples").GetFiles()
                   .ToLookup(f => f.Extension);
var videoFiles = myLookup[".wmv"].ToList();
```

Comment: What!? `Path.GetExtension(f.FullName)`!?  What is wrong with `f.Extension`?

Comment: Thanks for catching that one @John - oversight on my part